# How can I make the last sprite in an animation play for more than 1 frame?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 2D sprite animation of a waving flag, which I'm playing in a loop.

The problem I'm having is that the Unity Animation Editor is making the last sprite of my animation play for only one frame, whereas I have every other sprite playing for several frames.  So when the animation loops back to the beginning, the last sprite transition doesn't look smooth because the last sprite is visible for fewer frames than every other sprite.

Is there a way to increase the number of frames that my last sprite plays for in the Animation Editor?  Or is there a different way to handle this problem?

Here's my animation.  I circled where the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Click on the diamond above 0:00 and copy. Then go to 0:24 and paste it. First and last sprites look the same but if not that is the reason for this and what I propose must work.

Comment: I'll still have the same problem with the new sprite that I just added (that new sprite now only plays for 1 frame).

Comment: Aykut was right, it should loop, by having the last fame the same as the first.

Comment: @BugFinder It does loop on the last sprite that way, but the problem is that either the the first/last sprite plays for an extra frame (the first sprite's frames plus the last sprite's one frame) or I have to make the first sprite have one fewer frames.

Comment: All sprites are like a frame but by putting the keyframes you decide how long the sprites are shown. If you make first and last sprites the same the transition should be fine. Your order of sprites might be wrong. Delete the last one we added and try pasting the one at 0:16 to 0:24 and the one at 0:12 to 0:28 and etc. So all in reverse order including the first sprite.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear.  The problem is Unity gives the final sprite a playtime of 0:01 (and I can't figure out how to change that) and the other sprites have playtimes of 0:04.

Comment: The screenshot you put shows that your second and last sprites are same. Maybe that is the issue. it may look like repeating so delete the last sprite and past your first sprite as last one instead.

Comment: You dont change that,  having the last one makes it wrap, if that last one is 1 extra frame, then move the keyframe back so its not

Comment: @bugfinder so my first solution should work.

Comment: Only if it doesnt trim the frames, try adding a keyframe at the end without changing anything.. and we cant tell what changes on each keyframe other than "sprite" so its hard to know

Comment: Ben, when you add the first sprite to the end at 0:24, your last sprite (now at 0:20) will have 0:04 sec and it should loop back smoothly. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @BugFinder, Adding a keyframe without a sprite will look like blink, due to empty frame.

Comment: adding a keyframe at the end without changing anything is not the same as an empty one..... The sprite value remains the last one

Comment: @Aykut Oh, I see what you're saying now.  Yes, that worked.  Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @BugFinder The empty keyframe worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Ben would you please kindly accept my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the diamond above 0:00 and copy. Then go to 0:24 and paste it. First and last sprites look the same but if not that is the reason for this and what I propose must work.

Note: BugFinder's solution works as well:

> adding a keyframe at the end without changing anything is not the same as an empty one..... The sprite value remains the last one